# How to check Application Pool status remotely through SQL server

Tags: sql, ssis, plsqldeveloper

I am a SQL Database Admin and curious about is it possible to check Application pool site status remotely from DB server?

Is there any way (e.g. SSIS package or SQL script) that I can get the result in table or file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can't do this with native TSQL,you can use use WMI or Powershell

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. If you can give me Powershell script, I will execute via SSIS package.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629593/how-to-remotely-check-the-status-of-a-web-application-pool-with-powershell

Comment: try upvoting that answer,if it helps

Answer (score 1):

Execute SQL query in SQL server management studio as below :

```
 SELECT DB_NAME(dbid), COUNT(dbid) AS NoOfConnections, loginame 
 FROM sys.sysprocesses 
 WHERE dbid > 0 
 GROUP BY dbid, loginame
```